# Unable to zip and download files in unix server

Tags: java, unix, servlets, centos

I have hosted my java web application in a unix server the files are generated in a context path,zipped and downloaded to the client. My code is working once I have hosted the Application in a Windows server but not in Centos .. What could be the issue?

My zip Method:

```
private byte[] zipFiles(File directory, String[] files) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        byte bytes[] = new byte[2048];

        for (String fileName : files) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(directory.getPath()
                    + crbServlet.FILE_SEPARATOR + fileName);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                zos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
        }
        zos.flush();
        baos.flush();
        zos.close();
        baos.close();

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

My servlet Extract:

```
String[] files = f.list();
                    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                        byte[] zip = zipFiles(f, files);
                        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
                        response.setContentType("application/zip");
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"datafiles" + dt.getCurrentDate() + ".zip\"");
                        sos.write(zip);
                        sos.flush();
                    }
```

What I am getting downloaded on the client side is a do file that has junk character. What is the issue here?

Comment: How exactly are you so sure that the problem is in the code responsible for creating the zip file and not in the individual files themselves (or the code responsible for creating those individual files)?

Comment: I'd start with adding few logging lines to see, what files are being processed, their sizes, etc.